# How to pass value to Xcom in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, postgres-operator

```
last_updated_at = "{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='Match_Updated_date_{}', 
 key='QueryTimeStamp_{}')}}".format(country,country)
```

This is the value I am saving in my xcom

```
where last_updated_utc > '{}';
```

And using it in where clause

but the xcom is passed in correctly into my  where clause

```
 where last_updated_utc > '{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='Match_Updated_date_mm', 
 key='QueryTimeStamp_mm')}';
```

Its passing the entire String , how do I solved this?

```
.format(last_updated_at)
```

Thats how I am passing it in the where clause

When I was not using the

```
 my_xcom_value = "{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='Match_Updated_date', 
 key='QueryTimeStamp')}}"
```

The Xcom worked fine.but when I am passing parameter, It doesn't anymore

Python Callable function pushing the xcom

```
def match_dates(**Kwargs):     
try:     
print("enters the try block")     
response = s3.get_object(Bucket='mygluecrawlerbucket',Key='DateTime/Users/my_date_{}.txt'.format(Kwargs['key1']))
print("responce is ", response)
status = response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']
if status == 200:
print("Enters the status block ")
data = response['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")     
ti.xcom_push(key="QueryTimeStamp_{}".format(country), value=someVariable)
```

PostGresOperator pulling the xcom

```
import_redshift_table_zm = PostgresOperator(
        task_id='copy_data_from_redshift_zm',
        postgres_conn_id='postgres_default',
        sql="""
                BEGIN;

            create table angaza_public_spark.stag_angaza_users_zm as
            Select * FROM angaza_public_zm.users
            where last_updated_utc > '{}';
              END;
                   
    """.format("{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='Match_Updated_dates_zm', key='QueryTimeStamp_{}')}}".format(country))
```

Comment: What are `last_updated_at`  and `last_updated_at` ? Are those parameters of a custom Operator?

Comment: @NicoE, sorry I by mistake choose the same variable name. I have changed it now. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things,

1. Replace this

```py
{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='Match_Updated_date_{}', 
 key='QueryTimeStamp_{}')}}
```

with this (notice the space after `{{` and before `}}`

```py
{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='Match_Updated_date_{}', 
 key='QueryTimeStamp_{}') }}
```

2. Depends on where you are using `last_updated_at` parameter. Each operator in airflow has a class variable named `template_fields`

If you are using a custom operator, make sure you are adding `last_updated_at` as part of `template_fields`

For ex:

```py
template_fields = ('templates_dict', 'op_args', 'op_kwargs')
```

Comment: Could you please update the question with code, I'm unable to read it properly here..